# Area under zero almost everywhere step function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I feel like this is a basic question but I am having trouble getting rigorous. Given $f$ a nonnegative step function, hence we can write $f=\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_i \chi_{A_i}$ where $A_i's$ are disjoint measurable subsets and $f$ takes $a_i$ on $A_i$. Define $A(f)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_i m(A_i)$. If $f=0$ almost everywhere, then $A(f)=0$.

My attempt:

Let $N$ be the null set such that $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in N^c$. How do I continue? I am thinking of setting $A_i=(A_i \cap N)\cup (A_i\cap N^c)$, but I don't know how to manipulate $\chi_{A_i}$.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those are not step functions, they're simple functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exists $m \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ and $a_m>0$ then we must have $m(A_m)=0$ otherwise we would have that $f(x)>0\forall,  x \in A_m$ which contradicts hypothesis.

So in every case we have that every term of the linear combination has the form $0 \cdot a_i$ or $0 \cdot m(A_i)$ which are both zero.(Of course we have the agreement that $0 \cdot \infty=0$)

So $A(f)=0$

Comment: @TheGreatDuck  in MEASURE THEORY we have accept this result as a form of an axiom..see any measure theory text book..

Comment: @TheGreatDuck no i mean what i write..in measure theory we accept this result..in calculus especially in limits it is indeterminate but in measure theory we accept this fact..and this sort of axiom has a geometric meaning,not only an algebraic.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck i told you to look at any measure theory text book

Comment: @MariosGretsas Correct me if I'm wrong. Getting more precise, if $a_m>0$ and $x\in A_m$, then $f(x)>0$. Write $x\in (A_m\cap N)\cup(A_m\cap N^c)$. Observe that $x$ cannot be in $N^c$ as $f(x)=0$ there, so $x$ must be in $N$ and hence $A_m\subseteq N$ so $m(A_m)$ is zero by monotonicity. How is this?

Comment: @21understanding i believe it looks ok

Comment: @MariosGretsas Thanks. I have another basic problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458089/integral-when-limit-of-nondecreasing-simple-functions-greater-than-another-simpl that hopefully can get suggestions.